# Is <Type> redundant in this expression?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and came across the following function in the official handbook:

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
```

I understand that generics are used to make two different values correspond while maintaining specificity. However, I don't understand why `<Type>` is being used in the above function. Isn't the link between the parameter being accepted and the value being returned created by `(arg: Type): Type`? Thanks :)

Comment: What would `Type` refer to in those two places, if it weren't declared in the first place?

Comment: Consider that if you were to remove thje `<Type>` parameter, what _actual_ type-name would you specify for `arg`?

Comment: Oh I see, <Type> is declaring Type as the type variable. Otherwise TypeScript wouldn't recognize it. Thanks!

Comment: @JellaSchmidt Yes, in this case, though `Type` is a _type-parameter_, not a "variable". Also, it's customary to use single-character names for type-parameters (e.g. `T` and `U`) instead of `PascalCased` names, this is to avoid confusing type-parameters with "normal" types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
```

`<Type>` *declares* the generic type parameter. Later that is *used* as the argument type in `arg: Type` and return type `(): Type`.

If you removed the `<Type>` that would be an error because the `Type` is not the name of a type that exists.